# Why is my @Autowired null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I got a springboot application (i'm pretty new to it)

Here's my configuration class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.blah")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

All my classes are in com.blah.xxx packages.
I got another class, in the same package, in which I'm able to use the service by using context, not @Autowired :

```
@Component
public class MainClass implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        main(args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        ValueService service = (ValueService) context.getBean("valueService");
        System.out.println("blabla" + service.getValues().toString());
        context.close();
    }
}
```

I got a third class, still in same package and same module, in which I would like to use @Autowired but it's null :

```
@Component
public class ThirdClass{

@Autowired
private ValueService valueservice;

public ThirdClass() {

    valueservice.getValues(); // <-- Here valueservice is null

}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void check() {
        System.out.println("check");
    }
```

I know that @ComponentScan works well cause in my ValueService (which is in another module, but still package com.blah), I have a ValueDao which is @Autowired and this is working :

```
@Service("valueService")
public class ValueService {

    @Autowired
    ValueDao valueDao;
```

What's wrong here and how can I do to use @Autowired in my ThirdClass?
Thx!

Comment: Where and how do you get an instance of ThirdClass? If, as I suspect, you're ever using `new ThirdClass()`, then you have your answer. Don't do that. Autowire ThirdClass.

Comment: Actually in this class I use @Scheduled so I don't use new ThirdClass()

Comment: Post the code showing how and where you're getting an instance of ThirdClass.

Comment: I don't get any instance of ThirdClass anywhere, I suppose it just launch cause of the EnableScheduling, it get scanned by ComponentScan, and then method is called, I'll add the method above

Comment: Then you can't possibly have its valueService field being null. A field of an object doesn't exist at all if the object doesn't exist.

Comment: Should I then get my ThirdClass with context like I did with ValueService ? Even if i'll not call anything in it cause I will only have Scheduled methods in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access an Autowired field from inside the constructor of the object. That can't possibly work. Spring can't set the value of a field of an object if it doesn't have the object yet. And to have the object, its constructor must first be called. Ergo, at the time the constructor is called, the field is still null.

If you want to use a dependency after the bean is constructed, use a void method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Or do the recommended thing: use constructor injection rather than field injection.